# Show Lipschitz continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals

> Given 
>   $$(Su)(t) = h(t) + \int_{0}^{1}F(t,s,u(s))ds,$$ how do show that 
>   $$\|(I-S)u - (I-S)v\|\leq L\|u-v\|.$$

This is what i have 
Given $u,v \in G$, with Lipschitz constant $L>0$, let $\|u - k\|\geq m$, $\|v-k\|\geq m$, such that 
$\|(I-S)u - (I-S)v\|\leq L\|u-v\|$ holds
$$\begin{align}\|(I-S)u - (I-S)v\|&\leq L\|u-v\| = \|u - Su - v + Sv + k - k\|\\
                                 &= \|u - k - v + k - (Su - Sv)\|\\
                                 &\leq \|F(t,s,u(s)) - F(t,s,v(s))\|-\|u-k\| + \|v-k\|\\
                               & \leq\|u -v\|- m +  m
                                 \leq\|u-v\|.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

As stated the question is ill-founded, since you have not stated what spaces you're working on, what norms are in place, or the properties of the function $F$. However, this should get you started.

First, write down $(I-S)u - (I-S)v$ using the definition of $S$. We find that
$$
[(I-S)u](t) - [(I-S)v](t) = u(t) - v(t) + \int_0^1 [F(t,s,u(s)) - F(t,s,v(s))]ds.
$$
Taking norms, by the triangle inequality we find that
$$
\|(I-S)u - (I-S)v\| \leq \|u-v\| + \left\|\int_0^1 [F(t,s,u(s)) - F(t,s,v(s))]ds \right\|.
$$
The term $\|u-v\|$ is acceptable; as long as you can show that
$$
\left\|\int_0^1 [F(t,s,u(s)) - F(t,s,v(s))]ds \right\| \leq L\|u-v\|
$$
for some $L$, then it will follow that
$$
\|(I-S)u - (I-S)v\| \leq (1+L)\|u-v\|
$$
and we are finished: $(I-S)$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $1+L$. As for how you will actually show that the Lipschitz bound for the integral term holds: that depends entirely on the space of functions for $u$ and $v$, the properties of the norm, and the function $F$. One thing that is usually true is that you can take the norms inside the integral, i.e.
$$
\left\|\int_0^1 [F(t,s,u(s)) - F(t,s,v(s))]ds \right\| \leq \int_0^1 \|F(t,s,u(s)) - F(t,s,v(s))\|ds,
$$
but this is something that does need to be checked.

Comment: I am approximating a zero solution. I take G = I - S and G\neq \emptyset.